# npm install react-router-dom not working (vulnerabilities)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, cmd, router

My command prompt wasn't able to install react-router-dom due to 80 vulnerabilities that were found, and npm audit fix is not fixing anything. It says that all 80 should be reviewed manually, how can this be fixed? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the node_modules folder and package-lock.json then npm install

Comment: Your issue is with software configuration, and not a programming code issue. It should be posed on a more appropriate platform, [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) for instance.